# USB connection to xbox one

Tags: iokit, xbox-one

I am trying to create a USB connection from my mac to my xbox one so I can use the keyboard and mouse to simulate a controller.  I can not seem to find out how to connect the console and my computer in an IOKit connection to start sending data.  I am connected with a Type A male to Type A male USB cord. Upon queuing for devices that are connected like this,

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef matchingDict;
io_iterator_t iter;
kern_return_t kr;
io_service_t device;

/* set up a matching dictionary for the class */
matchingDict = IOServiceMatching(kIOUSBDeviceClassName);
if (matchingDict == NULL)
{
    return -1; // fail
}

/* Now we have a dictionary, get an iterator.*/
kr = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, matchingDict, &iter);
if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS)
{
    return -1;
}

/* iterate */
while ((device = IOIteratorNext(iter)))
{
    NSLog(@"%u",device);
    io_name_t devName;
    io_string_t pathName;
    IORegistryEntryGetName(device, devName);
    printf("Device's name = %s\n", devName);
    printf("\n");
    IORegistryEntryGetPath(device, kIOUSBPlane, pathName);
    IOObjectRelease(device);
}
```

Unfortunately nothing shows up that might be an xbox one device so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.  My question is how do I connect to the xbox one with my mac like a xbox controller would.

Comment: You'll need special (likely custom) hardware to do this. USB is a host/device protocol (not peer-to-peer), and you can't just cable two hosts together and have them talk.

Comment: Indeed. A type A male to male cable makes no sense whatsoever. You will need a device with two 'B' connectors, one for taking commands from the Mac, and another that pretends to be a game controller. There are probably microcontroller boards that can do this, although I've never done it myself so I can't recommend anything specific.